# Best way to keep data synced between modules (angularjs)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to MEAN, and recently followed this tutorial. http://www.bradoncode.com/tutorials/learn-mean-stack-tutorial/

In it, we create two modules, one for users, and one for categories. I would like to add a new "owner" property to the category model, such that upon creation a new category it is assigned the username of the user which created the category. This is easy enough, in the category controller, inside the $scope.create function, I add the line `owner: $scope.authentication.user.username`. The problem is when a user changes their username the categories "owner" property is not updated. Is there a way to have the owner property automatically updated with angularjs?

Comment: need to see how your services are being shared to be able to help more. Provide some of your code

Comment: Since my code is pretty much the same as the tutorial, I think it's easier if I link to the services code. https://github.com/bbraithwaite/NorthwindNode/tree/master/public/modules/users/services

https://github.com/bbraithwaite/NorthwindNode/blob/master/public/modules/categories/services/categories.client.service.js

Hope that helps.